# When refactoring a Java EE WebApp is useful?

Tags: java, web-applications, refactoring

I am dealing with a Java EE web application that needs some refactoring. I am currently in charge of doing this job and am currently at a loss on what would be necessary to be done or changed in order to improve the application.

My question is: **how can the frontend part be refactored?**

I already refactored the CSS files in order for them to have generic rules and classes and removing unused or wrong rules, I refactored all Javascript files using some patterns (not using prototype inheritance since it's not really useful here) and adding PrototypeJS and still need to finish aggregating JS functions (when possible) in Objects and included files.

Now I am finishing up adding *Localization* to pages that missed it or where it wasn't complete and I want to migrate the whole application to *XHTML Transitional* following W3C guidelines strictly.

I also have in mind to start using *Struts Tiles* to add templates and in the mean time remove the old "Tables Layout" the frontend is currently using, so actually redesigning the whole application.

But I am at a loss here: is what I am doing useful? Does all this work need to be done or am I just going too far? What would you add up? What would you do instead?

Comment: It sounds like you might have hit a very large piece of software and you're struggling with how it all fits together. Do you have specific concerns remaining about the code? I mean, is something wrong with it? If so, you can probably think of some more ways that you can address those concerns, or at least ask more specific questions about them. If not, it might be good enough as it is. Sometimes, complex software is complex because it has to be.

Comment: Actually I have a good grasp of how it fits together, I just had some doubts on what is really necessary to upgrade (improve) and what is just a matter of my taste (given the freedom I have this is not really a problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [Stack Exchange Thread (How to approach refactoring an existing web application?)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/27335/how-to-approach-refactoring-an-existing-web-application), would better answer your question.

Hope that helps.